# Syncing contacts between Outlook for Mac (2015) and Google Contacts

Tags: gmail, contacts, office-365

How to I sync contacts between Outlook for Mac (2015) and Google Contacts?

Answer (score 1):

**Can’t sync Outlook for Mac with calendars and contacts in Outlook.com, iCloud, Gmail accounts**

Outlook for Mac does not currently support CalDAV or CardDAV. This means that it is not possible to synchronize your Outlook on the web, iCloud, Gmail calendar or contacts with Outlook 2016 for Mac. However, Outlook 2016 for Mac does support iCloud Mail. For more information, see Microsoft Outlook 2016 for Mac compatibility with Apple iCloud.

For more known issues in Outlook 2016, pls check here:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Known-issues-in-Outlook-2016--for-Mac-af547e5c-4310-4d41-9944-08b1e842ebe4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US